# Control physic button using COM port or USB port

Tags: php, winforms, visual-studio

Here is my idea:
I current having a system to print tickets for patient. When you press the physical button on the machine, it will print a ticket, and this machine is connected to a computer via COM port.

Now, I want to press this button without touch it, I will use my code, but this is still a big problem with me because Iam just a web developer. My idea is I will connect this button with another computer via COM port (or USB port or any port that works), and use Visual Studio to build a software that when I click the button on this software - the "real" button will be pressed.

*at first, I though I will use php to build the website but I believe a software with Visua Studio will be much easier.

Is this possible? Sorry for my English, please leave comment if you don't get it. Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. But stackoverflow is not the proper channel to ask for how to build it. This is not a messageboard, but more of a knowledgebase. I recommend you do some more research about how to read from COM ports with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What have you got so far? try finding what key is pressed when you hit the button or look up instructions that make a certain keypress, then make a button with that key as the hotkey.

or add a keydown event to the form and check that the correct button was pressed
this will will be inside the keydown event.
replacing "TargetKey" with the key you want

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.TargetKey)
        {
            // code here
        }
else
         {
             // otherwise do blah blah
         }
```

very easily done

Comment: Thank you but the button is not a key on the keyboard. It is a button of a machine that connect to computer via COM port.

Comment: @KaZaT yes but should still return a keypress, get a key logger and press the button it will tell you what its equivalent to.

Comment: like a volume up button on headphones is equivalent to vol up on the device, your button should be equivlent to something

Comment: I installed Perfect Keylogger but There is nothing come from it (but other program is ok)